# Remove lines with first column containing specific character in BASH

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file with four columns like this:

```
11 9929261 9929261 LOC101928008
11 99556214 100356220 CNTN5
11_JH159136v1_alt 193978 194908 OR8U9
```

I need bash script to remove all lines that contain "_" in first column. 
Expected outcome would look like this:

```
11 9929261 9929261 LOC101928008
11 99556214 100356220 CNTN5
```

Even better if script can leave the line and first number of first column. In other words, remove all characters starting with "_" in first column of a file. In that case expected outcome would be like this:

```
11 9929261 9929261 LOC101928008
11 99556214 100356220 CNTN5
11 193978 194908 OR8U9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `awk` this can be done with something like:

```
awk '{split($1,a,"_");$1=a[1]}1' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed "s/^\([0-9]*\).* \([0-9]*\) \([0-9]*\) \(.*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/" < file.dat
#    ___----------__-__________-__________-______ -----------
#     1      2    3 4    5     6     7    8   9        10
```

explanation

1. use sed substitute from begin of line
2. extract first column (number) and save it in variable1  \1
3. ignore all chars without to next blank
4. blank
5. extract second column (number) in varaible2  \2
6. blank
7. extract third column (number) in variable3  \3
8. blank
9. extract the rest of line into variable4  \4
10. write variable1 to 4 with blank as separator